# SqlBulkCopy and ProgressBar in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, progress-bar, sqlbulkcopy

Actually, I am importing `Excel` file and saving records to `DB` through `SqlBulkCopy`
and everything goes fine.
Now,I need to show a `ProgressBar` while saving data through `SqlBulkCopy`.

My Code is :

```
SBC.WriteToServer(dsExcel);
SBC.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
SBC.NotifyAfter = 1;
```

and in the `SqlRowsCopied` event :

```
private static void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
{
//here i tried calling my progressbar. But I'm unable to call it.                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set that value right after you instantiate the object and before you call the WriteToServer Method:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlcpy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
    {
        sqlcpy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied); //<<---- You need to add this here
        sqlcpy.NotifyAfter = 1;
        sqlcpy.BatchSize = batchSize;
        sqlcpy.BulkCopyTimeout = 60;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlcpy.DestinationTableName = TableName;  //copy the datatable to the sql table
            sqlcpy.WriteToServer(dt);
            return sqlcpy.GetRowsCopied();
        }
    }
}
```

and it goes without saying but you also need a OnSqlRowsCopied event handler:

```
private static void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Copied {0} so far...", e.RowsCopied);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Actually now my event is firing.
but i'm unable to get the id of ProgressBar.

Comment: actually what this code "return sqlcpy.GetRowsCopied();" does?
i'm not getting any method for 'sqlcpy'